# What would be the best statistical method to ascertain whether there is a significant relationship between X and Y?

Tags: proportion, meta-analysis, effect-size

I am doing a meta-analysis to find out if those with disease X also have disease y. I am trying to find if there is a significant relationship between these 2 diseases. However, I am only given the total number of people with disease X (which is also the total sample size), the number of people with disease Y and the proportion of those with disease y. This doesn't seem like enough information to me (and I don't know how I would do an odds ratio with this). So what method would be best to find a significant relationship?

Comment: @asplre94 Is Y out of X ? How do you define proportion of those   with ...y ?

Comment: @subhashc.davar Yes Y is out of X for the proportions

Comment: If you could indicate your raw data in table or sheet format alongwith definitions . may facilitate understanding the problem

Comment: How many studies do you have for meta analysis?.

Comment: @subhashc.davar I have 40 studies

Comment: That means you have 40 proportions  -  each proportion  indicating proportion of people having Y alongwith X . Are you keen to do a meta analysis . I am not clear about odds ratio.

Comment: Since you only have people with disease X all you can do is to meta-analyse the proportion of people with Y. You have no way of comparing that with the prevalence of Y in the people without X. Would that answer your scientific question?

Comment: @mdewey Y IS OUT OF X. Certain people with X do not suffer from Y disease.

Comment: @subhashc.davar yes I know that, I am trying to clarify whether the OP has people without X as that would be necessary for the computation of an odds ratio.

Comment: @mdewey is right, here. The question can't be answered with the data given.  You could tell if the proportion is different from 0, but that's not the question. Mdewey, do you want to turn your comment into an answer?

Comment: @PeterFlom done. I like the mdewey is right <comma> here. True academic caution. I will clean up all my comments shortly to reflect the fact that I have answered.

Answer (score 3):

Since you only have people with disease $X$ all you can do is to meta-analyse the proportion of people with $Y$. It is perfectly possible to meta-analyse the (possibly transformed) proportions. This [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/81886/prevalence-conversion-to-effect-size-in-meta-analysis?rq=1) discusses one way of doing it with one transformation (logit) but there are other possibilities like log or Freeman-Tukey.

You have no way of comparing with the prevalence of $Y$ in the people without $X$ since you did not observe any of them. You could informally take literature estimates of the over all prevalence in the population and see whether that falls close to the summary from your meta-analysis I suppose..

Comment: Thank you very much! I was just given this data with no explanation of what I was suppose to do with it. I assumed that I would need to calculate an odds ratio before I got the data. But I now that I have the data, I do not have enough info for an OR. May talk to my supervisor about this... thanks though!

Comment: If you have further questions then best to edit them into your current question. If you do post a new question make sure to link back to this one.